# Missing vertical border to the left of Header in asp:Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, border

I have a asp:gridview with a header and paging but I'm wonderig that the vertical border to the left of the header is missing as shown in the image below (it is to the left of the string "Postnummer"):
[image]

As it can be seen it is only this little part of the gridview that is missing - every other border works correctly.

The declaration of the gridview is as follows:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvPost" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        EnableViewState="true"
        EmptyDataText="Listen er tom!" runat="server" CellPadding="4"
        ForeColor="#333333" Font-Size="Small" AutoPostBack="True"
        CssClass="Gridview"
        DataKeyNames="Postnummer"
        DataSourceID="odsRecords"
        AllowPaging="true"
        OnPageIndexChanging="gvPost_PageIndexChanging"
        AllowSorting="True"
        PageSize="50" GridLines="Both"
        ShowFooter="false" OnRowDataBound="gvPost_RowDataBound">
```

So what can I do to show this part of the vertical border?

I hope that someone can give me a hint.
Thanks in advance
Michael

Answer (score 1):

you should do it in the background like below

```
protected void gvPost_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
     {
         tc.Attributes["style"] = "border-color: #000000";
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering :-) But it fills in a border around each header - so what can I do for only choosing the outmost left vertical border?

Comment: Thanks - you have led me to the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows:

```
        protected void gvPost_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Style.Add("border-left-color", "#000000");
            }
        }
```